# Using new and assigning variable at the same time

Tags: go

```
wd := new(time.Weekday)
fmt.Println(wd.String())
```

The above two lines return Sunday (weekdays start with a 0)

Is it possible for me to assign a value along with new ? Other method i tried is

```
var wd time.Weekday
wd = 3
```

this one returns Wednesday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[time.Weekday](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Weekday) is an int so you can assign it as such (or use the defined constants as Adam suggested). Can I ask why you need to use new in this situation?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var wd time.Weekday = 3
    fmt.Println(wd)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use the time.weekday constants for that:

`wd := time.Wednesday`

Comment: i also want to assign a value to it in the same line

Comment: `time.Wednesday` is a value